# Variables (in some cases) not working inside `\href`

Tags: hyperref, variable

Given this small document class file `mycustomloc.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustomloc}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}

\newcommand{\address}[4]{
    \def\@neighborhood{#1}
    \def\@city{#2}
    \def\@state{#3}
    \def\@country{#4}
}

\def\@urlparams{\StrSubstitute{\@neighborhood+\@city+\@state+\@country}{ }{+}}
\def\@phoneparams{\StrSubstitute{\@phone}{ }{}}


\newcommand{\makecontact}{%
    Phone: \href{tel://\@phone}{\@phone}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    Why I can't add the variable urlparams in the \texttt{href} below if I
    can insert variables in the phone above (as you can see).

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    The content of `urlparams` is given below:

    \texttt{\@urlparams}.

    If add the ``string'' manually to \texttt{href}  it works:

    Loc.: \href{https://www.google.com/maps?q=Spring+Falls+Helena-West+Helena+AR+United+States+of+America}{\@city, \@state \,-- \@country}

    But adding the variable do not

    Loc.: \href{https://www.google.com/maps?q=\@urlparams}{\@city, \@state \,-- \@country}
}

\endinput
```

And this simple minimal working example `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{mycustomloc}

\address{Spring Falls}{Helena-West Helena}{AR}{United States of America}
\phone{+1 123 555-1234}

\begin{document}
    \makecontact
\end{document}
```

I'm not able to compile it if I use `\@urlparams` inside the `\href` (last one, is commented), but "manually" writting the string contents to the first parameter of `\href` works.

Why this behavior is ocurring and how to fix, since I want to be able to use the `\@urlparams` inside the `\href` command.

I also could not find any reasoning, since I'm able to use the `\@phone` variable inside the first `\href` call.

Comment: Related if not an exact duplicate: The real problem is the same and you can find some explanation there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476842/120578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mycustom.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustom}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}

\newcommand{\address}[4]{
    \def\@neighborhood{#1}
    \def\@city{#2}
    \def\@state{#3}
    \def\@country{#4}
}

\def\@urlparams{\StrSubstitute{\@neighborhood+\@city+\@state+\@country}{ }{+}[\first]\xdef\URLparams{\first}\first}
\def\@phoneparams{\StrSubstitute{\@phone}{ }{}}


\newcommand{\makecontact}{%
    Phone: \href{tel://\@phone}{\@phone}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    Why I can't add the variable urlparams in the \texttt{href} below if I
    can insert variables in the phone above (as you can see).

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    The content of `urlparams` is given below:

    \texttt{\@urlparams}.

    If add the ``string'' manually to \texttt{href}  it works:

    Loc.: \href{https://www.google.com/maps?q=Spring+Falls+Helena-West+Helena+AR+United+States+of+America}{\@city, \@state \,-- \@country}

    But adding the variable do not
    Loc.: \href{https://www.google.com/maps?q=\URLparams}{\@city, \@state \,-- \@country}
}

\endinput
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{mycustom}

\address{Spring Falls}{Helena-West Helena}{AR}{United States of America}
\phone{+1 123 555-1234}

\begin{document}
    \makecontact
\end{document}
```

Comment: No. It says: `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ...://www.google.com/maps?q=\URLparams `. Anyhow, can you explain what you tried to do?

Comment: Please test it again... I didn't change something, but had rename the class from your previous question... Pay attention to the names of the class in order to avoid a possible make a mistake... It supposed to work (tested) and it is a matter of expansion since I using a variable with `\xdef`... May be you didn't copy the whole code before... I have already defined the variable

Comment: Is there any good reason for the change in class name?

Comment: No, but Yes!... I was bored to rename the code in your previous question and just placed the code in the old files....